# How do I store previous used questions from ArrayA in ArrayB so that they can't be used again?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, switch-statement

Where and how do I take the already used questions and store them in a new array of 10 so the questions are not used again?

I also have the issue that it shoots out 11 questions before stopping.

I hope this enough code to give enough context. I have 359 lines of code, so not sure how much is needed to help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {//Beginning MAIN method braces
    
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String major;
    String level;
    int correctCounter = 0;
    int incorrectCounter = 0;
    
   
    Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);
    
    
    System.out.println("Please enter the following information:");
    System.out.print("First name: ");
        firstName = input.next();
      
    System.out.print("Last name: ");
        lastName = input.next();
        
    System.out.print("Your Major: ");
        major = input.next();
        
    System.out.print("College Level(Freshman, Sophmore, Junior, Senior): ");
        level = input.next();
    System.out.println();
```

//A string Array of 20 questions to be passed to the method
String[] questions = new String[20];

```
  questions[0] = "True/False: Cost is a potential disadvantage of teamwork?";
  questions[1] = "Ability is NOT a major aspect of culture that affects. True or False"
          + " communication.";
  questions[2] = "Which one is NOT a common technology used in meetings? \n"
          + "A. Workgroup messaging\n"
          + "B. Cellphones\n"
          + "C. Teleconferencing\n"
          + "D. Videoconferencing";
  questions[3] = "What is the first step in the listening process?\n"
          + "A. Evaluating\n"
          + "B. Remembering\n"
          + "C. Responding\n"
          + "D. Receiving\n"
          + "E. Decoding";
  questions[4] = "______ is the process of transferring information and "
          + "meaning betweem senders and receivers using one or more"
          + "written, oral, visual, or digital media. ";
  questions[5] = "______ are the accepted principles of conduct that govern"
          + "behavior within a society. ";
  questions[6] = "The listening process involves how many steps?";
  questions[7] ="iTranslate translates more than __ languages and features "
          + "voice input and output.";
  questions[8] = "What is 1/4 (one-fourth) in decimal form?";
  questions[9] = "What is the normal temperature for an adult, in `F?";
  questions[10] =  "A kite is stuck in the branches of a tree. If the "
  + "kite's 90 foot string makes an angle of 22 degrees to the ground,"
  + "calculate the distance in feet between the kite and the ground.";
  questions[11] = "If y=cos x, then what is the maximum value of y?";
  questions[12] = "What is 6^3";
  questions[13] = "What is 3^6?";
  questions[14] = "Round 672.4 to the nearest whole number.";
  questions[15] = " Round 14.6 to the nearest whole number.";
  questions[16] = "What is the max value of 15 32 10 99 87";
  questions[17] = "What is the min value of 15 32 10 99 87";
  questions[18] = "Groupthink occurs when peer preasure causes individual "
          + "team members to withhold contrary _____ and to go along with "
          + "decisions they don't really believe in. ";
  questions[19] = "Most people want to avoid letting others down, and "
          + "participating in teams creates a built-in sense of _______"
          + "to others. ";
  
  
  returning(questions, correctCounter, incorrectCounter);
  
  
   //Method call for TESTREPORT      
  report(firstName, lastName, major, level, correctCounter, incorrectCounter); 
 
      
}//Main end






public static double returning(String[] questions, int correctCounter, int incorrectCounter){//Beginning RETURN method start
    
    Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //Answers to the 20 questions stored in variables
    String answer0 = "True"; //Boolean answer
    String answer1 = "False";//Boolean answer
    char answer2 = 'B';//char answer
    char answer3 = 'D';//char answer
    String answer4 = "Communication";//fill in the answer
    String answer5 = "Ethics";//fill in the answer
    int answer6 = 5; //int answer
    int answer7 = 80;//int answer
    double answer8 = .25;//double answer
    double answer9 = 98.6;//double answer
    double answer10 = 33.71; //trigonometric question
    double answer11 = 1; //trigonometric question
    int answer12 = 216; //exponent question
    int answer13 = 729; //exponent question
    int answer14 = 672; //rounding question
    int answer15 = 15; //rounding question
    double answer16 = 99; //max value question
    double answer17 = 10; //min value question
    String answer18 = "opinions"; //free question
    String answer19 = "accountability";//free question
    
    
  
   
   int correctCount = 0;
   int incorrectCount =0;
   
   
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++){//Beginning FOR loop for switch statement
     correctCount++;
     incorrectCount++;
     
        //Random Number generator 
        int randomNumber = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * 20);
       
      
        //Switch statement
        switch (randomNumber){
            case 0 : System.out.println(questions[0]); 
                    String q0 = input.nextLine();
                    if (q0.equalsIgnoreCase(answer0)){
                     correctCount++;
                    }
                    else {
                        incorrectCount++;
                    }
                    break;
            case 1 : System.out.println(questions[1]);
                    String q1 = input.nextLine();
                    if (q1.equalsIgnoreCase(answer1)){
                       correctCount++;
                    }
                    else {
                        incorrectCount++;
                    }
                    break;
            case 2 : System.out.println(questions[2]);
                    String q2 = input.nextLine();
                    if (q2.equals(answer2)){
                        correctCount++;
                    }
                    else {
                        incorrectCount++;
                    }
                    break;
            case 3 : System.out.println(questions[3]);
                    String q3 = input.nextLine();
                    if (q3.equals(answer3)){
                        correctCount++;
                    }
                    else {
                        incorrectCount++;
                    }
                    break;
            case 4 : System.out.println(questions[4]);
                     String q4 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q4.equalsIgnoreCase(answer4)){
                        correctCount++;
                    }
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++; 
                    }
                    break;
            case 5 : System.out.println(questions[5]);
                     String q5 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q5.equalsIgnoreCase(answer5)){
                         correctCount++;
                     }
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++;
                     }
                     break;
            case 6 : System.out.println(questions[6]);
                     String q6 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q6.equals(answer6)) {
                         correctCount++;
                     }
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++;
                     }
                     break;
            case 7 : System.out.println(questions[7]);
                     String q7 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q7.equals(answer7)) {
                         correctCount++;
                     }
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++;
                     }  
                     break;
            case 8 : System.out.println(questions[8]);
                     String q8 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q8.equals(answer8)) {
                         correctCount++;
                     } 
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++;
                         
                     }
                     break;
            case 9 : System.out.println(questions[9]);
                     String q9 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q9.equals(answer9)) {
                         correctCount++;
                     }
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++;
                     }
                     break;
            case 10: System.out.println(questions[10]);
                     String q10 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q10.equals(answer10)) {
                         correctCount++;
                     }                
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++;
                     }  
                    break;
            case 11: System.out.println(questions[11]);
                     String q11 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q11.equals(answer11)) {
                            correctCount++;
                     }                
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++;
                     }  
                    break;
            case 12: System.out.println(questions[12]);
                     String q12 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q12.equals(answer12)){
                         correctCount++;
                     }                
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++;
                     }  
                    break;
            case 13: System.out.println(questions[13]);
                     String q13 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q13.equals(answer13)) {
                            correctCount++;
                     }                
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++;
                     }  
                     break;
             case 14: System.out.println(questions[14]);
                     String q14 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q14.equals(answer14)){
                         correctCount++;
                     }                
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++;
                     }  
                    break;
            case 15: System.out.println(questions[15]);
                     String q15 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q15.equals(answer15)) {
                            correctCount++;
                     }                
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++;
                     }  
                    break;
            case 16: System.out.println(questions[16]);
                     String q16 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q16.equals(answer16)){
                         correctCount++;
                     }                
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++;
                     }  
                    break;
            case 17: System.out.println(questions[17]);
                     String q17 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q17.equals(answer17)) {
                            correctCount++;
                     }                
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++;
                     }  
                    break;
            case 18: System.out.println(questions[18]);
                     String q18 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q18.equalsIgnoreCase(answer18)){
                         correctCount++;
                     }                
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++;
                     }  
                    break;        
             case 19: System.out.println(questions[19]);
                     String q19 = input.nextLine();
                     if (q19.equalsIgnoreCase(answer19)) {
                            correctCount++;
                     }                
                     else {
                         incorrectCount++;
                     }  
                    break;
             default : System.out.println("Error");
                    
        }//End SWITCH statment
        
    }//End FOR loop for switch statement
   
   
return correctCount + incorrectCount;


   

}//End RETURN method braces




public static void report(String firstName, String lastName, String major, 
        String level, int correctCount, int incorrectCount){//Beginning TESTREPORT method braces
    
    double percentCorrect = (correctCount/10);
    
    
    
    
    //print students input information, number of correct and incorrect +
    //questions and %correct
    System.out.println("Name: "+ firstName + " " + lastName);
    System.out.println("Major: " + major);
    System.out.println("College Level: " + level);
    System.out.println("Questions answered correctly: " + correctCount);
    System.out.println("Questions answered incorrectly: " + incorrectCount);
    System.out.println("Percentage correct: " + percentCorrect);


}//End TESTREPORT method braces
```

}//End CLASS method braces

Comment: You need to show the code you've written, and ask a specific question. Read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Should I delete this one and start a new one, or just add to it?

Comment: 1) `for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)` will loop with `i` having the values `0`, `1`, `2`, ... `10`  - that are 11 numbers - if you need only `10`, you must change the limits (start or end); 2) I would use some `List` instead of an array - they have variable length and it is easier to add/delete elements from lists; 3) we can;t see the whole code, but `switch (randomNumber) { case 0: ... question[0]` can be changed to `question[randomNumber]` (no `switch` needed)

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it to only generate 10 questions. I am required to use an array and switch.

Comment: are you sure it is meant to have a `switch` with 20 labels and have that much code repeated 20 times? Poor developer that has to maintain such code... I suggest you at least remove all duplicated code (the `switch` would only set a variable with the question text and the expected answer, all comparison and counting would be done only once after it)

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to display questions in a random order only once, then what you could do is shuffle the indexes to be presented in a queue structure.

The following method creates a list of the indexes from 0 to count - 1, shuffles them and returns a [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html) that when [poll()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html#poll()) is called will return the next index to offer up. Keep calling this until `null` is returned for no more questions.

```java
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

private Queue<Integer> questionOrder(int count) {
    List<Integer> indexes = IntStream.range(0, count)
        .mapToObj(n -> n)
        .sorted()
        .collect(toList());

    Collections.shuffle(indexes);

    return new ArrayDeque<>(indexes);
}
```

You could then use this as:

```java
private void askQuestions(String[] questions) {
    Queue<Integer> order = questionOrder(questions.length);
    System.out.println(order);
    Integer index;
    while ((index = order.poll()) != null) {
        String question = questions[index];
        System.out.println(question);
        // do your presentation logic.
    }
}
```